# Jquery- Pass javascript variable to PHP AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable from my javascript code over to the server side PHP code. I know this must be done via an ajax call which i believe i have done correctly, however i am failed to get it. Here is my code i have thus far:

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".search-box").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "readCountry1.php",
        data: { cat: $(this).val() },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $(".search-box").css("background","#FFF");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $(".suggesstion-box").show();
            $(".suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $(".search-box").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
    });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
    $(".search-box").val(val);
    $(".suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <div class="frmSearch">
        <input type="text" class="search-box" placeholder="Select Category" />
        <div class="suggesstion-box"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['cat'])){
    ?>
        <div class="frmSearch1">
            <input type="text" class="search-box1" placeholder="Enter Location" />
            <div class="suggesstion-box1"></div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

In above code i want to display second input box when a value is selected in first box. And here is my

**readCountry1.php**

```
<ul class="country-list">
    <?php
        require_once("dbcontroller.php");
        if(!empty($_POST["cat"])) {
            $query ="SELECT cat FROM catlist WHERE cat like '%$_POST[cat]%' UNION SELECT scat FROM catlist WHERE scat like '%$_POST[cat]%' ORDER BY cat";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
            if(!empty($result)) {
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
    ?>
                    <li onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $row["cat"]; ?>');"><?php echo $row["cat"]; ?></li>
    <?php 
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to pass my javascript variable "cat" to php ($cat), however i've gone wrong somewhere along the road.

Comment: You're setting the ajax request as POST, but you are supplying the data argument as a string. I'm not sure what the behaviour of this is, but are you not meant to instead pas an object?

Comment: `data: { cat: $(this).val() },`

Comment: @Chris Don't have enought knowledge about AJAX...Can you tell me solution of this...All i want is to display second text box when user select a value in first box...

Comment: @Jeff Working same as before....

Comment: 1- Your code is widely open to sql injection. 2- Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @EhsanT No i am not getting any sql error....nd do i need to use PDO for that  ??

Comment: What about JavaScript error? as I suggested, please check you console. Since you are using `mysqli` there is no need for `PDO` but you have to use `prepared statement` and not just put your variables directly in you query

Comment: Also please edit your post and change you `data` to what @Jeff has suggested so we know that you have a correct code which has some other problems that this one which is obvious

Comment: @EhsanT okay i will find some tutorial for that and definitely will work on it... And i am not getting any kind of error.....

Comment: So if you add `console.log(data);` in your `success: function(data){` block, what will you see in your console?

Comment: I have edited changes told by @jeff...

Comment: I have added console.log(data);...still nt displaying second text box....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134253/discussion-between-ehsant-and-ashish).

Answer (score 0):

In ajax set data in object format:

```
data: { cat: $(this).val() },
```

And

Send your response form server like this...

```
if(!empty($result)) {
    $data = "<ul>";
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $cat = $row["cat"];
                   $data.= "<li onClick='selectCountry(".$cat.")'>".$cat."</li>";
                }
     $data.="</ul>";         
            }
            echo $data;
```

Comment: Hi, I have made changes but code doesn't work even after changing my ajax and readCountry1.php..Text box doesn't display cat value on selection...